# PHP vertify against multiple criteria (more like I don't think this very long if statement is good.. code effiecentcy help!!)

Tags: php

So in PHP, I am checking a file extension against multiple types to get the general type of file

so here is what I have for images alone:

```
if ( $ext == "bmp" || $ext == "jpg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "psd" || $ext =="psp" || $ext == "thm" || $ext == "tif" || $ext == "ai" || $ext == "drw" || $ext == "eps" || $ext == "ps" || $ext == "svg" || $ext == "3dm" || $ext == "dwg" || $ext == "dxf" || $ext == "pln" )
```

I know that is crazy unefficient, considering the number of if-elses I'll also need to use. Is there another way of doing this to check files, or maybe a better, premade function (like apaches mime_Magic)? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve just this problem, you can do:

```
if(in_array($ext, $extensions))
```

and put those extensions in an array. Be sure you're checking the actual mimetype of the file, as well, rather than just blindly trusting the extension.

Comment: Cool! thanks! What is the best method of getting mimetype? I am seeing a few!

Comment: Doing a bit of searching on SO (for "php file upload secure" and the like) I found this neat tip from Pekka: after doing basic checks that it's an image file, use `imagecopy` to remove anything bad like PHP code that could be run by your having left a bad `include()` somewhere. That almost ensures that your image can't possibly have anything really all that bad in it, which is really the only issue: forgery.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this

```
$extensions = array("bmp", "jpg", "png", "psd", "psp", "thm", "tif", "ai", "drw", "eps", "ps", "svg", "3dm", "dwg", "dxf", "pln");
if (in_array($ext, $extensions))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mime content type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), [Fileinfo functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
   preg_match("/bmp|jpg|png|psd|psp|thm|tif|ai|drw|eps|ps|svg|3dm|dwg|dxf|pln/",$ext,$matches);
   print $matches[1];
```

Comment: Whoa now, looks like that'll match a file name like "modest_pln" with no extenton type.

Comment: the OP's $ext already has the extension. Look at the way he compares the variable.